# How to confirm a win 64 dll and its dependencies are also win 64?

Tags: dll, win64

My C++ un-managed component (dll) is compiled in Win 64 platform and used by a web API written in ASP.NET and hosted in IIS.

My web API works only when the C++ dll is placed under c:\windows\syswow64\inetsrv rather than c:\windows\system32\intetsrv.

I verified using sigcheck64.exe (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) to confirm that the dll I have compiled is in win 64 bit platform. When I used depends64.exe (dependency walker) tool to verify the dependency, I am unable to conclude if my dll and its dependencies are in Win 64 bit platform.

What is the best way / tool to check if my dll and its dependencies are in win 64bit platform?

Comment: Dumpbin.exe /headers is another way, the "machine" field (first listed value) identifies the target architecture.  That is the one that truly matters.  But quite doubtful that this explains anything.

Comment: Thanks. I used sigcheck64.exe and sigcheck.exe to confirm individual components.